# Stencil Start Error - TypeError("Parameter 'url' must be a string, not " + typeof url)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bigcommerce

I've worked with stencil for a while now, and am developing a custom theme for it, I've install nvm and node 5.0 and npm 2. I've also deleted stencil and did a fresh install of everything include node modules and stencil init But no matter what when running stencil start I still get the error below, I've googled the heck out of this and have come up empty so I'm hoping someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

```
  ⇒  stencil start
url.js:110
    throw new TypeError("Parameter 'url' must be a string, not " + typeof url)
          ^
TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined
    at Url.parse (url.js:110:11)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:104:5)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/server/index.js:14:31)
    at startServer (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/bin/stencil-start:188:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/bin/stencil-start:166:32
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/server/lib/stencil-token.js:55:24
    at finish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/wreck/lib/index.js:137:20)
    at wrapped (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:866:20)
    at ClientRequest.onResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/wreck/lib/index.js:158:20)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:199:16)
```

Comment: Try going down to Node 4.4.X. That is the latest supported/tested version. Are you on windows, linux, or os x?

Comment: Ah, also, according to your file paths, these are all areas owned by root. This may just be a permission issue of the application being unable to read the `.stencil` config file. Try running it as `sudo stencil init` and then `sudo stencil start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since solved the issue. The url is supposed to be set by stencil on Stencil init and then on Stencil start it matches them. It turns out, unbeknownst to me that the client's account had become inactive which means it no longer existed. In short, the url came up undefined because there was no url to be defined anymore being that the client no longer had one set up.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Stencil, but this error is being thrown because the URL is not set in your stencil config file (`./.stencil`). Is this something that is supposed to be set during `stencil init`? 
Specifically, you need to make sure these two values have been set in the `.stencil` file (which I assume to be a JSON config file, located in your project root directory):

1. **storeUrl** --------------*//The url to a secure page (prompted as login page)*
2. **normalStoreUrl** ---*//The host url of the homepage*

---

It might be useful knowing how to debug Node errors. Here's how my thought process went in reading & debugging:

**1.**

```
TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined
at Url.parse (url.js:110:11)
at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:104:5)
```

So the error is pretty straight forward. The program is attempting to parse a URL from string, but that string is undefined, thus causing the main error. Specifically, the node module `url.js` is attempting to do the parse.

Where is the URL supposed to be defined though? Let's continue on to see if we can figure it out.

**2:**

```
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/server/index.js:14:31)
```

https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/blob/master/server/index.js
Okay so let's open up this file and look at line 14, which reads:

```
module.exports = function(options, callback) {
    var config = manifest.get('/'),
        parsedSecureUrl = Url.parse(options.dotStencilFile.storeUrl), //Line 14 - The url to a secure page (prompted as login page)
        parsedNormalUrl = Url.parse(options.dotStencilFile.normalStoreUrl); //The host url of the homepage;
...
```

Alright, so we've located the exact line where the error is thrown (`parsedSecureUrl`). This URL should have been included in the options object used to initialize this module (`module.exports = function(options, callback) {}`)

Need to keep digging to see from where this options object is being defined, and how it is including its `dotStencilFile` property (`options.dotStencilFile`).

**3:**

```
at startServer (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/bin/stencil-start:188:5)
```

https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/blob/master/bin/stencil-start
Which reads:

```
 /**
 * Starts up the local Stencil Server as well as starts up BrowserSync and sets some watch options.
 */
function startServer() {
    var params = {
        dotStencilFile: dotStencilFile,   //It's getting set here!!
        variationIndex: themeConfig.variationIndex || 0,
        stencilEditorEnabled: Program.themeEditor,
        stencilEditorPort: Program.themeEditorPort || 8181,
        useCache: Program.cache
    };
    //Line 188 below:
    Server(params, function (err) {
        var watchFiles = [
            '/assets',
            '/templates',
            '/lang'
        ];
    ...
```

So we've located the function responsible for initializing and passing the `options` parameter to the module in step 2. Specifically, the variable is called `params` and the object that is supposed to contain the URL is `params.dotStencilFile`.

At this point, we just need to figure out what `dotStencilFile` is supposed to be.

**4:**

Searching through the source code in this file, I can see `dotStencilFile` being declared via:
`dotStencilFile = Fs.readFileSync(dotStencilFilePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'});`
So `dotStencilFile`'s value is set by reading a file from disk, located at `dotStencilFilePath`.

Last question then, what is its path? ...What is the value of `dotStencilFilePath`?

Easily enough for us, its value is defined in this same file: 
`var dotStencilFilePath = Path.join(themePath, '.stencil');` 
Where `themePath` = `var themePath = process.cwd();` (The current working directory of this file, assumingly the project root).

**5: (Solution)**
Okay so we got it! The file that is supposed to contain the URLs is called `.stencil` (a hidden file) that is located in the project root (`/Users/rob/myStencilProject/.stencil`).

This `.stencil` file is supposed to be a JSON file that contains the values for the two URL properties: `storeUrl` & `normalStoreUrl`.

I should check this file to make sure those properties have been set. Was I supposed to set them during `stencil init` perhaps? Can I set them manually? Either way, I am certain that the main error is being caused because this file does not contain values for the two above URLs.

---

---

Welp, I hope this information helps in solving both your current problem, as well as any others that you might come across during development. Good Luck!

Comment: This is a fantastic answer!! I love the way you debugged it and I think it is very useful information in general.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad to hear it made sense haha! Knowing how to arrive at a solution is much more empowering than just knowing the solution itself, and so I hope you are now a stronger developer because of it; Don't forget to give back to others ;-)